# protect users' file being accessed so only owner can access (pi)

Tags: pi-3

I have two users pi and bob and i have file that is `/usr/lib/docker/examples/basic_policy.csv`

I run `sudo chown pi:pi -R /usr/lib/docker/examples/basic_policy.csv`
 and its work but still the file could be open by bob

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How did you create user bob? What are his access rights?

Comment: This is a generic Linux question. You might have better luck at https://unix.stackexchange.com/.